# Why is my project Euler problem 1 code returning an answer of 232169 instead of 233169 (when I input a 1000)?

Tags: python, math, sum

It's all in python, I understand it's not great or very efficient but I'm still learning. Any help on the subject title and on any efficiency gains would be much appreciated!

```py
# Problem 1 - find all the multiples of 5 and 3 between 0 and a number (including the number).
import math

print("This programme finds all the multiples of 5 and 3 between 0 and a number (including the number) and also finds "
      "the sum.")

number = int(input("Input a natural number: "))
amount_of_threes = math.floor(number / 3) + 1
# The +1 is due to the 'stop' value not being included in a for loop (for i in range(start, stop))
multiples = []


for i in range(1, amount_of_threes):
    multiples.append(i * 3)

amount_of_fives = math.floor(number/5) + 1

for i in range(1, amount_of_fives):
    multiples.append(i*5)

# must get rid of duplicates such as 15 which is a common multiple
unique_multiples = []
for item in multiples:
    if item not in unique_multiples:
        unique_multiples.append(item)

unique_multiples.sort()

print(f"These are all the multiples of 5 and 3 below {number}: {unique_multiples}")

total = 0
for item in unique_multiples:
    total += item

print(f"{total} is the total of the multiples.")
```

I tried 1000 which was assigned to the variable 'number', got 232169, should have got 233169. a difference of a 1000.

Comment: Please reread the original problem statement, and review your choice of range.

Comment: @KennyOstrom The code takes measures to include 1000.

Comment: FYI, `math.floor(number / 3)` can be simplified to `number // 3`

Comment: Instead of checking if an item is in `unique_multiples`, why not just check if the number is a multiple of 3 before adding the multiple of 5 to `multiples`?

Comment: The simple way to get rid of duplicates in a list is with `unique_multiples = list(set(multiples))`

Comment: Python has a built-in `sum()` function, you don't have to write a loop.

Comment: So `total = sum(set(multiples))` will do everything in one fell swoop.

Comment: your code, as posted, prints `234168`, which is the correct answer (given that you choose to include the final number). Note that the original problem says "below 1000", that is, the final number is not included.

Comment: @Barmar: this is not how you solve this problem.

Comment: Also, the problem says "natural numbers". 0 is not a natural number, but your code counts it when calculating `amount_of_threes` and `amount_of_fives`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sayed, Welcome to stack overflow.

I want to answer to your question considering that you said "I'm still learning" python. I hope my answer is useful to you.

In your algorithm, you basically take these steps:

- calculate how many multiples of 3 there are in the range (hint).
- create a list with these multiples.
- calculate how many multiples of 5 there are.
- append these multiples to the list.
- create a list of unique multiples.
- iterate this list of multiples to verify it is not in the unique multiples list.
- sort the unique multiples list.
- get the total of the unique multiples in the list.

Some comments:

1. When you have a list of numbers, you don't need to sort it to get the total.
2. You can use the function `sum` to get the total of a list of numbers. It also iterates on the list, but it is a more elegant code.
3. In any given problem, try to iterate the least amount of times: only once if possible.
4. This algorithm has a complexity of N^2

Consider this code (iterating only once, checking the condition at the same time):

```
N = 1000

total = 0
for n in range(1, N):
    if n%3==0 or n%5==0:
        total += n

print(total)
```

Or taking advantage of python's rich expressiveness, in a one liner:

```
print(sum(n for n in range(1, N) if not (n%3 and n%5)))
```

This code has a complexity of N, that still could be prohibitive in some instances (try to solve it for N = 1e12).

Another solution, not using brute force could be this:

- calculate how many multiples of 3, 5 and 3*5 there are in the range (you had this hint in your first step)
- calculate the sum of numbers from 1 to n for each of the previous multiples
- multiply each sum by the multiple in question

The following code solves it with constant complexity:

```
N = 1000

sumto = lambda    n:  n*(n+1) // 2 # 1+2+3+4+...+n
mults = lambda m, n: (n-1) // m    # number of multiples of m below n

print(3*sumto(mults(3,N)) + 5*sumto(mults(5,N)) - 15*sumto(mults(15,N)))
```